# Java String encoding - Linux different than on Windows

Tags: java, linux, encoding

I have created a java program (REST) service. The whole development / testing was done on Windows, now the deployment to production-test is in work. However, there is "small" encoding problem occurred:

```
String s3 = new String("grÃ¼n".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
logger.info(s3);
logger.info("das ist wirklich grün");
logger.info(new String("das ist wirklich grün".getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8"));
```

I receive through HTTP-attributes (the web application is hosted on tomcat, behind an apache which has an auth plugin) a few values I have to process. They are coded like you see in line 1. (This value is shown on both Windows and Linux).

When I convert it to UTF-8 like in line 1 and write it to the log-file (log4j) I have the term "grün" (which is correct) on my Windows machine. On the linux server I still have the same output.

Then I tried to directly use Umlaute (üäö etc), like in line 2, and both on Windows and Linux the value is written correct into the log-file. I then tried to do some convert like in line 3, however, the same result: both operating systems show the same result.

Both machines have the same Locale in Java (Locale.getDefault()) -> I tried that already. I'm not able to change the way the value is inserted into the HTTP-Request!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Both machines have the same Locale in Java (`Locale.getDefault()`) -> I tried that already.

It is the default charset, not the default locale that determines what character set is used when decoding / encoding a string without a specified charset.

Check what `Charset.defaultCharset().name()` returns on your Windows and Linux machines.  I expect that they will be different, based on the symptoms that you are reporting.

Comment: Yes, thank you, that hint is in the right direction. Windows machine uses windows-1252 whereas Linux uses UTF-8.

Comment: using String s3 = new String("grÃ¼n".getBytes("windows-1252"), "UTF-8"); does the trick, now it is also correct on a linux machine. However, I don't why I have to use the windows charset on linux, maybe the string is originally created on a windows machine...

Comment: *"... maybe the string is originally created on a windows machine."* - Probably yes!

Comment: @karlis: window1252 is very close to Latin1 or iso-8859-1. This encoding has long been a standard and is still often a default when the protocols do not allow to specify encoding, for example for GET request parameters in HTTP. De facto standards change slowly...

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is invalid:

```
String s3 = new String("grÃ¼n".getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

What happens here: You get the bytes for the string `"grÃ¼n"` using the default character encoding of the system that you are running this on (because you didn't specify an encoding in the call to `getBytes()`) and then you convert those bytes back to a `String`, specifying that these bytes are UTF-8 encoded text:

characters => bytes in default character encoding (which may or may not be UTF-8) => convert back to characters as if the bytes are UTF-8 encoded text

That will obviously only work correctly if the default character encoding of the system is UTF-8. On Windows it is not (it's probably [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)).

Strings by themselves do not have a [character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding). There is no such thing as "an UTF-8 string" or "converting a string from X to UTF-8". A character encoding specifies how characters in a string are converted to bytes and vice versa, but is not a property of the string itself. You *can* have an array of bytes which represents text encoded in a specific character encoding. (Just like "decimal" and "hexadecimal" is not a property of a number itself, just how you present a number).

Don't write your program in such a way that it depends on the default character encoding of the system it's running on; that means, don't call `getBytes()` on a `String` without specifying the character encoding, for example (and there are other API calls that use the default encoding if you don't specify it).

Comment: Thank you! You are correct, it should not be used that way. However, improving is always possible after finding the real problem and a solution.

Comment: Yes, so the solution is: check your program for places where it relies on the default character encoding, and fix those places so it doesn't.

Comment: It's the only part where I have to use something like this. And thanks to your answers it now does what it should.

Comment: I can only mark one answer as correct. :) But both answers led me to the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Please compare the JVM version on both environment. This is most probable issue related to encoding.